# Why can't i render several occurence of a component with setState?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I'm working on a dashboard page. My goal is to let user add several occurences of a component, save it and restoring it. For now, i'm testing it with a hard coded save (an array of object with 2 fields).

My problem here is that i think i'm using setState in a wrong way. I'm trying to restore the components by calling a "setComponent" in a for loop and giving it the right arguments from the save but there is a lot of thing i don't understand.

First, my function RestoreArea is called 2 times and i don't know why because i've only called it once.
Next, i think i'm doing a bad "for loop" because the console says that it can't render infinite component or something like that.

Here's my code :

```
import { React, useState } from 'react'
import { CCarousel, CCarouselItem, CImage, CButton, CAlert } from '@coreui/react'
import { AreaModule } from 'src/components'

const Areaboard = () => {
  const [components, setComponents] = useState([])
  const [save, setSave] = useState([{ Text: 'Not Saved', Status: 'warning' }])

  let area_save = [
    { action: 1, reaction: 2 },
    { action: 0, reaction: 0 },
    { action: 3, reaction: 3 },
  ]

  //fonction pour recupérer la backup dans area_save

  function RestoreArea(area_save) {
    console.log('hey')
    for (let i = 0; i != area_save.length; i++) {
      console.log('jjj')
      setComponents([...components, area_save[i]])
    }
  }

  if (area_save.length > 0) RestoreArea(area_save)
  else area_save = [{ action: 0, reaction: 0 }]

  function addComponent() {
    setComponents([...components, { action: 0, reaction: 1 }])
  }

  function changeSaveStatus() {
    setSave([save, { Text: 'Save done !', Status: 'success' }])
  }
  return (
    <div
      style={{
        display: 'grid',
        flexDirection: 'row',
        justifyContent: 'space-around',
        gridAutoFlow: 'row',
      }}
    >
      {save.map((item, i) => (
        <CAlert color={item.Status} key={i}>
          {item.Text}
        </CAlert>
      ))}
      <CButton onClick={addComponent} type="submit" color="primary" height={20}>
        Add Area
      </CButton>
      <CButton onClick={changeSaveStatus} type="submit" color="primary" height={20}>
        Save Config
      </CButton>
      <div
        className="item"
        style={{
          display: 'grid',
          justifyContent: 'space-around',
          flexDirection: 'row',
          alignContent: 'center',
        }}
      >
        {components.map((item, i) => (
          <AreaModule
            size={500}
            key={i}
            name={i.toString()}
            action={item.action}
            reaction={item.reaction}
          />
        ))}
      </div>
    </div>
  )
}

export default Areaboard
```

I tried a lot of things but i can't say what. mostly trying things randomly because i'm not use to setState for the moment.

Answer (score 0):

You are calling setState in a loop, setState re-renders the component so your function is re-running again everytime u setState which will cause your function to run again, in addition to your if statement :
if (area_save.length > 0) RestoreArea(area_save)

area_save.length > 0 is always true here so it will keep calling RestoreArea hence generating the infinite loop

Comment: yeah it's normal because that was a test. my problem is that even if i try to loop only 3 time, it says it's an infinite loop even if it's not.

Is there a way to call addComponent multiple time in a row ?